# Show that $f(x)=x^2+\frac{a}{x}$ cannot have a local maximum for any value of $a$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Show that $f(x)=x^2+\frac{a}{x}$ cannot have a local maximum for any
> value of $a$.

I have tried to find the derivative here.
$$f(x)=x^2+\frac{a}{x}$$
$$f'(x)=2x-\frac{a}{x^2}$$
As, derivative is zero or undefined at critical points,
$$2x=\frac{a}{x^2}$$
$$x^3=\frac{a}{2}$$
$$x=\sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{2}}$$
Also, $f'(x)$ is undefined at $x=0$.
Now, how can we prove that the critical points do not give a local maximum without knowing value of $a$.
I can see that there are no local maximums from it's graph.

[image: graph]

But how to prove it?

Comment: Try to calculate the second derivative.

Comment: You only need to analyze the curve for $ \ a \ > \ 0 \ \ . $  For $ \ a \ < \ 0 \ \ , $ we can write $$ x^2 \ + \ \frac{-|a|}{x} \ \ = \ \ x^2 \ + \ \frac{|a|}{-x} \ \ , $$ which is the vertical reflection ("horizontal flip") of $ \ x^2 \ + \ \frac{|a|}{x} \ \ . $ So the conclusions we reach about the $ \ a \ > \ 0 \ $ curve  will apply to its "mirror image".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just consider the second derivative as well.
You already have that all critical points fulfil $x_0^3=\frac{a}{2}$.

The  second derivative is $$f''(x)=2+\frac{2a}{x^3}$$ hence $f''(x_0) = 6> 0$.
So if $x_0$ is an extremum it's a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to study the sign of $f'(x)$ you get that it is always positive in a right neighborhood of $ 
x = \sqrt[3]{{\frac{a}{2}}}
$
and negative in a left neighborhood of the same point. This suffices to say that  $ 
x = \sqrt[3]{{\frac{a}{2}}}
$ is always a local minimum.

P.s the inequality
$
2x^3  - a > 0
$ is satisfied for
$
x^3  > \frac{a}{2}
$
so that $
x > \sqrt[3]{{\frac{a}{2}}}
$
whatever is the sign of $a$.

Comment: Can you please explain how we can analyse the signs without knowing value of a?

Comment: How do we get the inequality? I'm really confused.

Comment: One criterion to detect if a point x_0 is a local minimum or a local maximum is the study of the sign of $f'(x)$ in a neighborhood that point. If the sign is positive on in the left neighborhood and negative in the right neighborhood, then you have a local maximum.  If the sign is negative on in the left neighborhood and positive in the right neighborhood, then you have a local minimum. That's way we set down the inequality.